# Is it possible to perform shell command substitution without using a subshell?

Tags: shell, directory

I have a scenario that calls for command substitution without using a subshell. I have a construct like this:

```
pushd $(mktemp -d)
```

Now I want to exit and remove the temporary directory in one go:

```
rmdir $(popd)
```

However that doesn't work because `popd` doesn't return the popped directory (it returns the new, now current, directory) and also because it's performed in a subshell.

Something like

```
dirs -l -1 ; popd &> /dev/null
```

will return the popped directory but it can't be used like this:

```
rmdir $(dirs -l -1 ; popd &> /dev/null)
```

because the `popd` will only affect the subshell. What is called for is the ability to do this:

```
rmdir { dirs -l -1 ; popd &> /dev/null; }
```

but that's invalid syntax. Is it possible to achieve this effect ?

(note: I know I can save the temporary directory in a variable; I was trying to avoid the need to do so and learn something new in the process!)

Comment: I'd save the directory to a variable; that way, a `trap` handler can cleanup the directory should the process be poked by a signal.

Comment: The answer is _no_.

Comment: It looks like on `fish`, the equivalent of command substitution, `()`, changes the outer shell's folder. It's usually annoying, but in cases like this it's useful, I'm sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The choice of the title of your question is a bit confusing.

`pushd`/`popd`, a `csh` feature copied by `bash` and `zsh`, are a way to manage a stack of remembered directories.

```
pushd /some/dir
```

pushes the *current* working directory onto a stack, and *then* changes the current working directory (and then prints `/some/dir` followed by the content of that stack (space-separated).

```
popd
```

prints the content of the stack (again, space separated) and then changes to the top element of the stack and pops it from the stack.

(also beware that some directories will be represented there with their `~/x` or `~user/x` notation).

So if the stack currently has `/a` and `/b`, the current directory is `/here` and you're running:

```
 pushd /tmp/whatever
 popd
```

`pushd` will print `/tmp/whatever /here /a /b` and `popd` will output `/here /a /b`, not `/tmp/whatever`. That's independent of using command substitution or not. `popd` cannot be used to get the path of the previous directory, and in general its output cannot be post processed (see the `$dirstack` or `$DIRSTACK` array of some shells though for accessing the elements of that directory stack)

Maybe you want:

```
pushd "$(mktemp -d)" &&
popd &&
rmdir "$OLDPWD"
```

Or

```
cd "$(mktemp -d)" &&
cd - &&
rmdir "$OLDPWD"
```

Though, I'd use:

```
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d) || exit
(
  cd "$tmpdir" || exit # in a subshell 
  # do what you have to do in that tmpdir
)
rmdir "$tmpdir"
```

In any case, `pushd "$(mktemp -d)"` doesn't run `pushd` in a subshell. If it did, it couldn't change the working directory. That's `mktemp` that runs in a subshell. Since it is a separate command, it has to run in a separate process. It writes its output on a pipe, and the shell process reads it at the other end of the pipe.

ksh93 can avoid the separate process when the command is builtin, but even there, it's still a subshell (a different working environment) which this time is emulated rather than relying on the separate environment normally provided by forking. For example, in `ksh93`, `a=0; echo "$(a=1; echo test)"; echo "$a"`, no fork is involved, but still `echo "$a"` outputs `0`.

Here, if you want to store the output of `mktemp` in a variable, at the same time as you pass it to `pushd`, with `zsh`, you could do:

```
pushd ${tmpdir::="$(mktemp -d)"}
```

With other Bourne-like shells:

```
unset -v tmpdir
pushd "${tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)}"
```

Or to use the output of `$(mktemp -d)` several times without explicitly storing it in a variable, you could use `zsh` anonymous functions:

```
(){pushd ${1?} && cd - && rmdir $1} "$(mktemp -d)"
```

Comment: I understand `pushd` and `popd` to work as you describe and that they're independent of command substitution - no confusion there! However, you answered by own problem by revealing `$OLDPWD`. I can do `popd; rmdir $OLDPWD`. That;s the answer to my problem - everything else just confirms what I thought. Command substitution appears to be a way to solve it but it isn't because of the subshell and you can't do command substitution without a subshell, So thanks for revealing OLDPWD - that's exactly what I need!

Comment: @starfry, `rmdir $(popd)` causes `popd` to run in a sub-shell which means it won't change the current directory, but even if it did not run in a subshell, the output of `popd` will not be the temporary directory, it will be a space separated list of directories not including that temp dir. Which is where I'm saying you're confused.

Comment: but I thought I had said that in my question: "popd doesn't return the popped directory (it returns the new, now current, directory) and also because it's performed in a subshell." Admittedly it returns a list, but the first in the list is the one I was referring to.

Comment: @starfry, OK sorry. Let's say I was the one confused by the title of the question and didn't read the rest carefully enough.

Comment: well your answer was still good and pointed me in the right direction. I never knew about that shell variable `OLDPWD`. I must remember to one day read `man bash` from end-to-end !

Comment: @starfry, note that `$OLDPWD` and `cd -` are standard (POSIX) `sh`. `pushd`/`popd` are only csh/tcsh/bash/zsh/yash/fish.

Answer (score 2):

You could unlink the directory first, before leaving it:

```bsh
rmdir "$(pwd -P)" && popd
```

or

```bsh
rmdir "$(pwd -P)" && cd ..   # yes, .. is still usable
```

but note that `pushd` and `popd` are really tools for interactive shells, not for scripts (that's why they are so chatty; real scripting commands are silent when they succeed).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem so I'll post my solution here.
Apparently there's not a way to avoid to span a subshell when using `$(command)` so the only solution that I got is to use a global variable -> pass it to the function and use `eval`.
My case was a bit trickier.
I wanted to open a file descriptor in a function and pass back the fd number to the main function.
The problem is that the file descriptor is opened in the subshell and not in the main:

```
open_fd_and_return() {
    local _my_file="${1}" _my_fd_no

    exec {_my_fd_no}>"${_my_file}" || die "impossible to open the fd"
    echo "${_my_fd_no}"
}
my_file="$(mktemp --dry-run)"
my_fd="$(open_fd_and_return "${my_file}")"
echo "test $$" >&"${my_fd}"
rm "${my_file}"
exec {my_fd}>&-
```

this return "bad file descriptor error"

my solution for now is to use eval (even if uglier)

```
open_fd_and_return_eval() {
    local _my_var="${1}"
    local _my_file="${2}"
    local _my_fd_no

    exec {_my_fd_no}>"${_my_file}" || die "impossible to open the fd"
    eval "${_my_var}=\${_my_fd_no}"
}

my_file="$(mktemp --dry-run)"
my_fd=""
open_fd_and_return_eval "my_fd" "${1}"
echo "test $$" >&"${my_fd}"
rm -- "${my_file}"
exec {my_fd}>&-
```

This works.
Hopefully this is useful for someone.

Comment: If using `ksh93`/`bash`, you can also use `typeset -n` to pass the fd var by reference.

Comment: Using the `$REPLY` variable to return something (or `$reply` for lists) is also common practice. See also [Are there any conventions for the name of global variable that holds function's result?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/365412)

Answer (score 0):

In bash, `dirs` provide a list of remembered directories by the pushd/popd method.

Also, `dirs -1` prints the last directory included in the list.

So, to remove the directory created previously by executing `pushd $(mktmp -d)`, use:

```
rmdir $(dirs -1)
```

And then, `popd` the already removed directory from the list:

```
popd > /dev/null
```

All in one line:

```
rmdir $(dirs -1); popd > /dev/null
```

And adding the option (-l) to avoid the `~/x` or `~user/x` notation:

```
rmdir $(dirs -l -1); popd > /dev/null
```

Which is remarkably similar to the line you asked for.
Except that I would not use `&>` as it would hide any error reporting by `popd`.

Note: The directory will remain after `rmdir` as it is the `pwd` at that point. And will be actually unlinked after the `popd` command (no remaining links used).

---

There is an option to use, for shells that support the variable "OLDPWD" (most bourne-like shells: ksh, bash, zsh have `$OLDPWD`). It is interesting to note that [ksh does not implement dirs, pod, pushd by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/984635/2350426) (lksh, dash and others also don't have popd available, so, are not usable here):

```
popd && rmdir "$OLDPWD"
```

Or, more idiomatic (same list of shells as above):

```
popd && rmdir ~-
```

Comment: The problem with this, and what I was trying to solve, is that you cannot `rmdir` the current directory which is where you'd be when doing this. You need to effect the `popd` before doing the `rmdir` but you need to know what to remove and `popd` does not tell you that. I, like you, thought `dirs -l -1` was the answer but have since discovered that the answer is actually to use `$OLDPWD`.

Comment: @starfry I believe that the shortest answer is to use: `popd && rmdir ~-`.

Comment: @starfry You could actually remove the current directory, no problem, provided it is empty (without forcing the erase). You could even call `rmdir "$PWD"` all right. Also, the current directory should be the one created by `mktmp -d` (if `pushd $(mktemp -d)` was executed beforehand) and to which `pushd` moves the pwd.  So, yes, **after** `pushd` and **before** popd, the directory created is stored in `$(dirs -1)`, I fail to see any problem.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the generic

> Is it possible to perform shell command substitution without using a subshell?

question, command substitution in the `fish` does not run in a subshell:

```
$ set dir (cd /etc; and pwd)
$ echo -- $dir $PWD
/etc /etc
```

Does change the current working directory and sets `dir`.

ksh93 and recent versions of mksh also support a `${ cmd; }` form of command substitution that doesn't run in a subshell.

```
$ dir=${ cd /etc && pwd; }
$ print -r -- "$dir" "$PWD"
/etc /etc
```

`mksh` uses a tempfile for that.

With other shells, you can always use a tempfile:

```
cmd > "$tempfile"
output=$(cat<"$tempfile")
```

Comment: I can't wrap my head around the idea of creating a file on the FS to store the contents of a transient variable.